# Common algorithm issue while trying to send an email using C#

Tags: c#, sendmail, smtpclient, mailmessage, sspi

I'm trying to send an email via my C# application, but every time i try to send the email, an error occurs, saying "**A call to sspi failed**", when i look at the inner exeption it says something like "**The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm**"

My code is this:

```
try
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("sender@domain.com", "Sender");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("receiver@domain.com", "Receiver");
    const string fromPassword = "Pass123";
    const string subject = "Prueba";
    const string body = "Prueba body";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smpt.domain.com",
        Port = 25,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure,
        BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}
catch (Exception exc) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error: {0}", exc.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

And on my App.config i have something like:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="sender@domain.com">
        <network host="smtp.domain.com" port="25" userName="sender@domain.com" password="Pass123" defaultCredentials="true" />        
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Is it correct that the password for your sender differs between code and config, or is that just where you've redacted real data?

Comment: No, i've just modify the real data and i skip that, i will correct it

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://www3.trustwave.com/support/kb/article.aspx?id=11849

- Navigate to Control Panel.
- Administrative Tools and then Local Security Policy.
- Local Policies and Security Options.
- System Cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing.
- Disable the setting, and then click Apply.
- Restart the IIS

Comment: I've just tried that, now i'm getting a different error, "Sending email failure" and the inner exception is "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Comment: I have tried this [link] (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2014/05/01/encountering-quot-the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-algorithm-quot-or-sec-e-algorithm-mismatch-0x80090331.aspx) but i can't figure out which **cipher** is my server using

Answer (score 0):

At the end i just give up with using SmtpClient and MailMessage, i used Outlook MailItem

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

oMsg.To = "correo@gmail.com";
oMsg.Subject = "Prueba";
oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

oMsg.HTMLBody = "<html><body>";
oMsg.HTMLBody += string.Format("<p>El dato {0}", var1);
oMsg.HTMLBody += string.Format("se guardo en la  <a href='{0}'>dirección</a>.</p> </br> <p>Saludos.</p> </body></html>", path);

oMsg.Display(false); 
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oMsg).Send();
```